# KeyPress de un DataGridView

Tags: c#

Tengo este codigo para copiar los valores de una celda de un DataGridView en un TextBox de otro formulario, funciona OK pero me copia los datos de la siguiente fila, cuando doy ENTER en una fila determinada copia el dato de la siguiente fila.

Alguien me podria decir donde esta el error.

gracias a todos

```
if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
{
fjdCompras frmCompras = fjdCompras.GetInstancia();
string parC1;
parC1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["idoperador"].Value);
frmCompras.setProveedor(parC1);
this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende en que lugar se ejecutando el código.
Trata de verificar el evento o método que se ejecuta el código, puedes estar llamándolo en otro lugar o que el evento lo este asiendo.Una pequeña sugerencia, haces primero el llamado de lo que ocupas y luego lo envías, luego es mas practico para hallar los errores cuando son muchas lineas

```
if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
{
  string parC1;
  parC1 = Convert.ToString(this.dataListado.CurrentRow.Cells["idoperador"].Value);
  fjdCompras frmCompras = fjdCompras.GetInstancia();
  frmCompras.setProveedor(parC1);
  this.Hide();
}
```

Posdata:
 Otra manera de realizar la obtención de datos de la celda es por su número

```
idpersona = Convert.ToInt32(DtgPrueba.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```